# Installs node v0.10.31, Gets node v0.10.29

Tags: web-server, node.js

When I tried to install node.js v0.10.31 from http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/, I end up installing node.js v0.10.29 instead of v0.10.31.

I removed `node` via `apt-get` and redid the procedure, but still ended up with the wrong version.

Any ideas?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
Selecting previously unselected package node.
(Reading database ... 68746 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking node (from node_latest_armhf.deb) ...
Setting up node (0.10.29-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node -v
v0.10.29
```

Checked the node version inside the REPL as well, its also v0.10.29:

```
> process.versions
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.29',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.27',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1h' }
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the package before with `sudo dpkg --remove node`?

Comment: @MorganCourbet Just tried your suggestion after installing node v0.10.30, and now I'm back to v0.10.28. Do you think the wrong version of node.js was being hosted as the latest version?

Comment: I don't think so since if you look inside the `.deb` package at `node_latest_armhf.deb/control.tar.gz/control.tar/./control`, you will see `Version: 0.10.31-1`. But this string is only for the package, not necessarily for the software itself. The version string when you do `--version` or `-v` for most of the softs is often contained in the binaries). Try to extract the `.deb` somewhere just to see if this is actually version 0.10.31. If so, we will try to install the package properly.

Comment: @MorganCourbet How should I extract the `.deb`?

Comment: Well, I use an awesome soft called `dtrx` (stands for Do The Right eXtraction. Install it with `sudo apt-get install dtrx`). All you have to do is `dtrw node_latest_armhf.deb`. You have the binaries in `node_latest_armhf.deb/data.tar.gz/data.tar/./usr/local/`. You will have to find a way to run nodejs from the extracted directory (because of the dependencies in `/include`, `/lib`, and `/share` in the same directory). I cannot dive into this right now (@work) but there should be some articles around the web.

Comment: @MorganCourbet Thanks for the suggestion to use DTRX, but I cant seem to figure that out. I checked the node version using REPL (updated post) and it also shows v0.10.29.

Comment: I repeated the steps and somehow its now 0.10.31!

Answer (score 1):

It simply seems the site has pointed "latest" to the wrong version. Any combination of

- Wait until they discovered and corrected that
- Use version 0.10.30, available at the site
- Download the source from http://nodejs.org/download/ and build it yourself

should set you on your way.